# Why does this lambda expression not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, python-3.8

trying to swap two elements of a list by using lambda expression, but it is not working.

 can someone tell me why it doesn't work?

```py
>>> swap = lambda lst, a, b: lst[a], lst[b] = lst[b], lst[a]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to lambda
```

Comment: A lambda only supports [expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html), it does not support [statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html).

Comment: [Why can’t lambda expressions contain statements?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-lambda-expressions-contain-statements). [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) ,

Comment: Often if you search SO with the Exception's error message you'll find what you need.